# QuickFIX/J how to disable auto logon response

Tags: java, quickfix

I'd like to perform some operations after receiving LOGON message and then decide if LOGON failed or not (for example check username and password) but...
Immediately after receiving LOGON message QuickFIX/J resends:

```
8=FIX.4.4|9=74|35=A|34=13|49=FIXserver|52=20110831-09:27:41.847|56=localhost|98=0|108=10|10=131|
8=FIX.4.4|9=71|35=2|34=14|49=FIXserver|52=20110831-09:27:41.855|56=localhost|7=1|16=0|10=213|
```

How to disable this functionality?

Second question. If LOGON failed, should I resend LOGOUT message or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call you required methods which do your logon checkins and other checks in *onLogon*. You can disable sending messages in toAdmin. Entry points for messages is *fromAdmin* and sending point is *toAdmin*.

No need to send logout message as logon didn't happen. You logout out of a session only if you have logged in.